# Kendo Validate - Ignore Specific Inputs

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-validator

I am using Kendo validation to do some light front end validation.

I am using an external API, that does the back end validation for me, so I only need to validate a few inputs for format/required.

Currently, it is validating every input.

How can I specify elements to ignore.

I realize I can specify specific elements to validate, but I don't want to take this approach, as there are way more elements to validate than not to validate.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried this? It talks about hidden fields but you can apply this to any field. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850265/how-do-i-get-kendoui-validator-to-ignore-hidden-form-elements

Comment: what validation did you use and do you have a specific condition? you can create your custom validation and use them whenever you wanted

Answer (score 5):

You can set the disabled attribute on the input element for him to be ignored.

```
<input type="text" disabled></input>
```

in jquery:

```
$("input").prop("disabled",true);
```

or

```
$("input").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

The basic form element ignores the disabled fields for validation and serialization, I tried on with kendo validator and it works.

Here the question for html form:
[How can I manipulate a form / inputs to be ignored when a form is submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775276/how-can-i-manipulate-a-form-inputs-to-be-ignored-when-a-form-is-submitted)

Hope it helped!
:)

**UPDATE**

Just found that if you set to the input element the attribute "data-validate='false'" he will ignore because he uses this selector to get all the inputs to validate:

```
"$(':input:not(:button,[type=submit],[type=reset],[disabled],[readonly])[data-validate!=false]')"
```

Comment: data-validate='false' Saved me. Thank you @7win https://stackoverflow.com/users/3174199/7win